# Removing notification from Mac notification center

Tags: macos, web-push, safari-push-notifications

Mac OS Big Sur
11.2.3

Developing Web Push notifications per [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/PushNotifications/PushNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013225-CH3-SW1).  Just got to the point where the popup appears and I can confirm permission. The notification gets added to my notification center, but I can't delete it to try again for debugging.

Posts I've found on this talk about using the 'delete' key or Fn+backspace, but that doesn't work for me.

How do I do this please?

Comment: I have a feeling this is very bad bug from Apple. Having the same trouble on Monterey 12.4 and this is ludicrous. No delete button works, NotificationCenter folder does not even exist in Library folder. If someone does have a solution, would be great to know.